# MyOb duplicate contacts being pushed in company file API

Tags: php, myob

I am trying to push contacts from my Database VIA API

http://developer.myob.com/api/accountright/v2/contact/customer/

It push the contacts fine, but when i t revoke company file access (i reset myob_id in DB while doing it) & try sync again.

it pushes the Customer duplicate.

Can anyone help me avoid duplicate record creation in myob company file after call API to create contact.